# Is it possible to add Spring MVC project template to intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

[image]

Hello guys! Is it possible to add Spring MVC project template (img above) to newer versions of intellij IDEA? As far as I know, this feature was removed in newer versions (post v14). p.s.: I don't wanna use spring boot.

Comment: Are you using community edition? For me it is there by default but I m using paid version.

Comment: No, Im using latest ultimate version

Comment: There is a [new wizard](http://i.imgur.com/sutQvDw.png) specifically for Spring.

Comment: @CrazyCoder actually, its a step before "Create project from template"

Comment: Projects templates is a completely unrelated feature.